# Error when syncing MySQL database (XAMPP) on Dropbox

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a MySQL database for local development using XAMPP, and I would like to work on two different computers. Looking online, I saw this [link](http://www.pmkelly.com/2012/07/sync-xampp-dropbox/) that gives a tutorial on syncing your database using Dropbox. I've successfully made it work on one computer, but not on the second computer and can't figure out what's wrong. Here are my steps:

**Computer 1**

1. Shut down Apache and MySQL on XAMPP control panel
2. Copy the entire contents of `C:/xampp/mysql/data` into `C:/Users/Steven/Dropbox/.../data`
3. Change the following lines in the `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` file:

   ```
   datadir="C:/Users/Steven/Dropbox/.../data"

   innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/Users/Steven/Dropbox/.../data"

   innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/Users/Steven/Dropbox/.../data"
   ```
4. Restart Apache and MySQL, and it works successfully

**Computer 2**

1. First, made sure the XAMPP server was shut down on the first computer
2. Made sure XAMPP server was shut down on second computer
3. Change the local C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini file as in step 3 for the first computer
4. When I start up the server and MySQL, I get the following error in the XAMPP control panel:

   ```
    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
    5:05:33 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
   ```

And here is the output from the log file:

```
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 17e0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625987 and 1625987 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1638951 in the ib_logfiles!
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data  pages 
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 1638951
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] IPv6 is available.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
     2014-06-06 13:31:19 7276 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
     Version: '5.6.16'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: There is no error here, I see only normal startup messages.
If you refer to crash recovery process then, well, this is expected if you backup MySQL like that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the xampp control panel error message.